# Node server can't read ES6 and React.js syntax codes

Tags: node.js

As I want to use server rendering with React, I'm trying to use [this starter project](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/ssr). However, `server.js` file is written in ES6 syntax, so when I deploy it to Node production server, it says something like `import express from "express";`, which means it can't read ES6 syntax. I know it can be replaced `const express = require('express');`, but that doesn't solve everything as there are React component code which is something like the following.

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={sheetsManager}>
        <App />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>,
  );
```

I need my Node server to be able to read ES6 and React syntax. Can anyone explain how I can acheive it based on [this starter project](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/ssr)?

P.S. the project has some babel configuration by having `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]`, but it doesn't work when I deploy it on my Node server. Did I miss something?

Comment: Is it possible that your server does not have `yarn` installed? Your example project start script depends on `yarn`, which can be replaced with `npx` if that happens to be the problem.

Comment: > (...) doesn't work when I deploy it on my Node server ... please describe how it doesn't work. Any exception, syntax, runtime error ?

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski When I checked the server log, it says `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from "express";` which means Node can't read ES6 syntax

Comment: That's reasonable, node doesn't support new import syntax. But stating that it doesn't work while deployment implies that it works locally for you. Does it ?
Looks like you're have different local and deployment setup, show the details of how you run/transpile your stuff.

Hint, i've used this in my project some time ago: https://gist.github.com/zbigg/979e985ecfea707d0087aa400eaa47e0